# What is @ISA in Perl?

Tags: perl, perl-module

If I have a module with methods `a` and `b` and want to export them I do:

```
use Exporter;  
our @ISA = qw (Exporter);  
our @EXPORT = qw (a b);
```

What I don't understand is what does this line:
`our @ISA = qw (Exporter);` do?

Comment: See `perldoc perlobj` and `perldoc perltoot`.

Comment: It makes no sense to export methods?!? Do you mean "subs"?

Answer (score 15):

The `@Foo::ISA` array is a global variable that holds the classes from which class `Foo` inherits.

Generally, you shouldn't manipulate `@ISA` directly; doing so is a sign that you're probably looking at old Perl code.

If you want to declare an inheritance relationship, a better way to do it is

```
use parent 'Exporter';
```

which tweaks `@ISA` behind the scenes for you and also does some other useful stuff.

In your case, when you do

```
our @ISA = qw(Exporter)
```

you're declaring your class as a subclass of `Exporter`. The `Exporter` class provides a method called `import`. Why do you want that? Because when you say

```
use MyClass;
```

What actually happens is:

```
BEGIN { 
    require 'MyClass.pm';
    MyClass->import;
};
```

The `import` method is automatically called every time someone `use`s your class. That method can do anything you want. (You could write your own `import` if you want to) but usually it's used to import symbols into the caller's namespace. That's what `Exporter` does for you.

However, `Exporter` also exports its own `import` method, so you don't actually have to inherit it any more. (This was fixed a loooong time ago.) So now you can just say

```
use Exporter qw(import);
```

and your package will get the `import` method without having to mess with `@ISA` at all.

Answer (score 9):

Think *object oriented* here.

Think of Exporter not as a mere module, but as a *class*. Think of `ISA` as meaning "Is a" as in *"My module **is a** sub-class of Exporter"*.

What you're doing is declaring your module as a sub-class of the Exporter class which means you can use the `import` method of the Exporter class which is sort of useful.

To really explain what Exporter is doing, you must understand that Perl uses Namespaces. Imagine if your program has a variable<sup>1</sup> called `$total`, but so does the module you're using. Your `$total` variable would interfere with the module's `$total` variable.

To prevent this, Perl uses namespaces. Your program operates in the default *namespace* of `main`. Your modules use the `package` function to declare a new *namespace*. Now, both you and your module can safely use a variable called `$total`. In your program, it's really `$main::total`, and in the package, it's $Package::Name::total`. If you want to use something from one _namespace_ in another, you can prepend the _namespace_ on it. Think of the`$File::Find::name`and`$File::Find::dir`variables you have when you use`File::Find`.

What the Exporter's `import` method does is copy your subroutines (and if you so desire, your variables) from your namespace to the current namespace. Imagine using the `File::Copy` module without the ability to *copy* over the `copy` subroutine to your main namespace. You could still use it, but you'd have to give it the name of the namespace on it:

```
use File::Copy;

...

File::Copy::copy( $from_file, $to_file );
```

Thanks to Exporter (and the import method), any subroutines you put into your packages `@EXPORT` array are copied over to the current namespace. Thus, you can access File::Copy`s`copy` subroutine like this:

```
use File::Copy;

...

copy ( $from_file, $to_file );
```

This is also why you must declare all of these variables as `our` and not `my`. `my` variables are *lexically scoped* and cannot be accessed outside of where they're declared. Package variables (like `$File::Find::name`) can be. For `Exporter` to find your `@EXPORT`, and `@EXPORT_OK` arrays, these need to be *package* variables.

Now, comes the desirability of exporting functions...

The oldest modules that we know and love export subroutines willy-nilly. You use File::Copy, File::Path, File::Find, and you have immediate access to their subroutines. This is because they put their subroutines into the `@EXPORT` array. This was at one time thought desirable because it makes these functions immediately available to you.

Newer modules like `File::Temp` require you to declare the subroutines you want to import:

```
use File::Temp qw(tempdir);

...
my $temp_dir = tempdir;
```

If I didn't have that `qw(tempdir)`, I couldn't use the `tempdir` function.

This is considered polite. The module is asking your permission to import the function. This is done by putting the subroutines into `@EXPORT_OK`. These will only be exported upon request.

This is better because you don't have to import everything, just what you need. And, you're documenting where these functions are defined.

Object Oriented modules don't export anything at all and don't need to use Exporter. It's been a long time since I've written a module that uses Exporter.

--
<sup>1</sup> We're talking about *package* variables here. Package variables are visible everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The `@ISA` package variable is used to specify inheritance between classes. You are discouraged to manipulate this variable yourself. If you want to inherit from another class, do

```
use parent 'Parent::Class';
```

or pre v10.1:

```
use base 'Parent::Class';
```

In this specific case, inheriting from `Exporter` makes the `import` method available. Your code could be rewritten as.

```
use parent 'Exporter';
our @EXPORT = qw/a b/;
```

The `import` method is called automatically when your module is `use`d, and may export symbols to the using package.

---

Why using `@ISA` manually is bad:

- Do not assign to `@ISA`: Other modules may have already added entries to it; this would overwrite them. Therefore, `push @ISA, "Some::Class"`.
- Avoid modifying `@ISA` during runtime. It is better to specify the inheritance relationship as early as possible (during parsing or after initial compilation), so that your module could be used there without restrictions. You could wrap it in an `BEGIN` or `CHECK` block, like

  ```
  BEGIN {
    push @ISA, "Some::Class";
  }
  ```

Inheritance via `parent` makes this much easier. `parent` will also compile the requested module if it isn't already loaded: no need for `use Some::Class`.

Comment: But why do I need to explicitely write it? After that I don't use it

Comment: @Jim I don't understand. The Exporter module allows you to export symbols from your package when it is `used`. This is implemented with the `import` method. You can either write one yourself (error-prone) or inherit a versatile implementation from `Exporter`. Inheritance is internally represented with the `@ISA` array.

Answer (score 3):

It instructs Perl to look in the `Exporter` module for methods when it can't find them in your package. The usual method you want to inherit from `Exporter` is its `import` method, which is where the work of copying your module's exported symbols to the calling package takes place.

From `perlobj`:

> Each package contains a special array called `@ISA`. The `@ISA` array contains a list of that class's parent classes, if any. This array is examined when Perl does method resolution, which we will cover later.

For example, this is an error because Perl will try to call the non-existent subroutine `Foo::some_method`:

```
sub Bar::some_method { 42 }
my $obj = bless {}, 'Foo';
$obj->some_method;
```

The `@ISA` variable in a package tells Perl to look for the method in other packages, so this code will work and invoke the `Bar::some_method` method.

```
sub Bar::some_method { 42 }
my $obj = bless {}, 'Foo';
@Foo::ISA = qw(Bar);
$obj->some_method;
```

The practical application for this is inheritance.

As amon mentions, there is rarely a need to set `@ISA` directly. The `parent` pragma (and the older, now discouraged `base` pragma) declare inheritance relationships and set this variable for you.